# Using printf outside of an array when using pointers to an array

Tags: c, pointers, printf

I'm trying to get a better understanding of pointers and arrays and I stumbled across an example I can't make sense of

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    char s[] = "bear";
    char(*a)[4] = &s;
    char(*b)[3] = &s;
    char(*c)[2] = &s;
    char(*d)[1] = &s;

    printf("%c%c%c%c\n", a[0][0], b[0][1], c[1][0], d[2][1]);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Running the code I get "b e a r"

The way I understand it each line says "this is an array of characters of x lenght, its' first element is this (&s)" and when searching for something out of the bounds of the array it will interpret the next bunch of data in the memory as another array (which may or may not give undefined behavior depending on what was written there).

so a :

b e a r

---

b :

b e a

r

---

c :

b e

a r

---

d :

b

e

a

r

---

where to rows are `[x][]` and the columns are `[][x]`

everything checks out except `d[2][1].`

`d` only has one column `d[x][0]`, I would expect to get a segmentation error or undefined behavior when reaching for `d[2][1]`, just as I would get if I ran `b[1][2]`, but instead "r" is printed. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d[2][1]` is the same as `*(d+2)[1]` which is the same as `*(*(d+2) + 1)`

```
d[0][0] -> b
d[1][0] -> e
d[0][1] -> e
d[1][1] -> a
d[2][0] -> a
d[0][2] -> a
d[3][0] -> r
d[2][1] -> r
d[1][2] -> r
d[0][3] -> r
```

Answer (score 0):

C allows those fancy things. When you get out of `d` but you are still inside `a` you are safe.

```
char(*a)[4] = &s; // a is a pointer to int[4]
char(*b)[3] = &s; // b is a pointer to int[3]
char(*c)[2] = &s; // c is a pointer to int[2]
char(*d)[1] = &s; // c is a pointer to int[1], which is equivalent to int
```

All 4 variables has the same starting address. But here is what happens when you `move` each pointer:

```
a[1] == s[4] // When you add 1 to A, it will jump the size of int[4]
b[1] == s[3] // When you add 1 to B, it will jump the size of int[3]
c[1] == s[2] // When you add 1 to C, it will jump the size of int[2]
d[1] == s[1] // When you add 1 to D, it will jump the size of int[1]
```

You can check the following:
`printf("is b[2] ==  c[3] ? %d\n", b[2] == c[3]);`

The comparison is doing something like this: `s + 2 * sizeof(int[3]) == s + 3 * sizeof(int[2])? => s + 2 *sizeof(3 ints) == s + 3 * sizeof(2 ints)? => YES`

Be aware that by doing that you are already outside of `s`, so trying to dereference it will probably cause you trouble! I'm just comparing addresses, not playing with the values stored in them.